# Div reappears after using .hide() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

I've checked all similar questions and tried different solutions, but with no luck at all.

I've got a very simple div to catch a name and surname. What I  want to do is, if the input boxes are not empty, post to another page (with jquery), remove or hide div1 and show div2 to ask a question(div 2 is hidden).

For some reason, when I hit the submit button, the name and surname are post to the other page and stored in the database, but after the alert, div1 reappears and div 2 disappear. Could anyone give me a hand here please?

Thank you very much!

Jquery code:

```
    <script>
        function saveDetailsToDB()
        {

            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;

            if (name === "" && surname === "") 
            {
                alert("Please, enter your details!");
                $("#UQ").css( "display", "none");   

            }

            else if(name !== "" && surname === "")
            {
                alert("Please, enter your Surname");
                $("#UQ").css( "display", "none");

            }

            else if(name === "" && surname !== "")
            {
                alert("Please, enter your Name");
                $("#UQ").css( "display", "none");
            }
            else
            {

                $.post("saveDetails.php",{ name: name,surname: surname });
                $("#detailsDiv").hide();
                $("#UQ").show();
                alert('You have been successfully registered!');

            }   
        }
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div id = "detailsDiv">
        <form>
            <b><label>Name:</label></b><br> 
            <input type = "text" id = "name"><br><br>

            <b><label>Surname:</label></b><br>
            <input type = "text" id = "surname"><br><br>
            <button onclick="saveDetailsToDB();">Send</button>
        </form>

    </div>

    <div id = "UQ">
    <b><label>Please enter your question.</label></b><br><br>
    <form>
        <textarea id = "question" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea><br><br>
        <button onclick="saveQuestionToDB()">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because you don't prevent the default action of the button click, so the page reloads which makes the content look like it reappears. Try this:

```html
<button onclick="saveDetailsToDB(); return false;">Send</button>
```

Or better still, remove the outdated `onclick` attribute from your HTML and attach the events using JavaScript:

```html
<button class="btn-save">Send</button>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.btn-save').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var name = $('#name').val();
        var surname = $('#surname').val();

        if (name === "" && surname === "") {
            alert("Please, enter your details!");
            $("#UQ").hide();
        }
        else if(name !== "" && surname === "") {
            alert("Please, enter your Surname");
            $("#UQ").hide();
        }
        else if(name === "" && surname !== "") {
            alert("Please, enter your Name");
            $("#UQ").hide();
        }
        else {
            $.post("saveDetails.php", { 
                name: name,
                surname: surname 
            });
            $("#detailsDiv").hide();
            $("#UQ").show();
            alert('You have been successfully registered!');
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a million Rory!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.